# Enforce tag creation for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have been trying to create a policy that will not allow an ec2 instance to be created unless it has a Project tag. Here is what I have now and all I get is `ec2:RunInstances You are not authorized to perform this operation` even with I have the tag Project.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "RunCloudFormation",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "cloudformation:*"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "*"
          ]
      },
      {
          "Sid": "CreateEC2Instances",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "ec2:Describe*",
              "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
              "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
              "ec2:CreateTags",
              "ec2:RunInstances"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "LaunchingEC2withAMIsAndTags",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
          "Condition": {
              "StringLike": {
                  "aws:RequestTag/Project": "?*"
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Here is a snippet of my CloudFormation template:

```
  "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Project",
            "Value": "test"
          },
          {
            "Key": "OwnerAdmin",
            "Value": "myname"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "TESTTags"
          }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the policy simulator to allow the RunInstances action by changing

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
```

to

```
"Resource": "*",
```

You only need to use the resource level permissions if you want to constrain resources used by the instance, such as AMI, subnet, security group, etc.

Comment: Thank you: I did that still getting API: ec2:RunInstances You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: Have you tried only using the multi-character matching wildcard (*)?

Comment: Here's my last suggestion, if this doesn't work I'll whip up an example. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Null